# Opengl incorrect layering after rotating scene

Tags: opengl

I have two quads forming two sides of a cube.. both have textures mapped to them.

At first the layering is fine (the nearer side is 'on top' of the further side). However when I rotate the scene, the layering breaks as the layer which should now be at the back is still on top.

Do I need to manually clear the z-buffer or something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds like you haven't enabled depth testing. Try `glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)`.

And by the way, yes, you do need to explicitly clear the z-buffer every cycle, by running `glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`. If you aren't doing that, then the reason that's not causing you trouble already is also likely because you're not using the depth buffer since you haven't enabled depth testing to begin with.

(In the likely case that you're already clearing the color buffer every cycle, you can combine the two into `clClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)`.)

Comment: This is probably the issue. I'd just add that with a convex object, this wouldn't be strictly necessary with `glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE)` and correct (CCW vs CW) winding conventions.